# Cannot access custom python modules in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-module

I have installed some custom module. I have imported them through python console but when I try to import them in my pycharm project it does not recognise the module.

Comment: Check the settings to make sure you are using the proper Interpreter and make sure the module is in the pythonpath for that interpreter, It's under preferences... Than pick project and interpreter

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm, use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open settings. Under **Project:Exp**, select **Project Interpreter**. Use the "+" icon to install any module.